# How to get all subfields of mongodb in a query when one field is root field of other field requested?

Tags: mongodb

For this specific case, everything works fine, except when
for the fields `field1`,`field2` requested, and `field1` is a part of `field2`.

Example :

```
> db.mycoll.findOne()
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "data" : {
        "amounts" : {
            "dollar" : 20,
            "euro" : 18
        },
        "item" : "toy",
        "sale" : false
    }
}

   // works well
> db.mycoll.findOne({"_id":1},{ "data.amounts.dollar":1 })
{ "_id" : 1, "data" : { "amounts" : { "dollar" : 20 } } }



   // here "data" is root of "data.amounts.dollar" and "data.amounts.euro" 
   //   takes preference, how to query for "data", so 
   //   that all subfields of data are 
   //     returned
> db.mycoll.findOne({"_id":1},{ "data":1 , "data.amounts.dollar":1 })
{ "_id" : 1, "data" : { "amounts" : { "dollar" : 20 } } }
```

Expected output :

```
 {
        "_id" : 1,
        "data" : {
            "amounts" : {
                "dollar" : 20,
                "euro" : 18
            },
            "item" : "toy",
            "sale" : false
        }
    }
```

Yes, it is possible to format the subfields on the program side, and send the root field to mongodb query, but my question is if this is feasible on the querying side without Javascript .

Comment: Have you tried `db.mycoll.findOne({ "_id": 1 }, { "data": 1 })`?

Comment: @chridam The requirement is with both fields "data" and "data.amounts.dollar" included together.

Comment: @DhruvPathak  If you were to try aggregation `db.mycoll.aggregate({$match:{"_id":1}},{$project:{ "data.amounts.dollar":1, "data":1 }})` then you'll get this error `"can't add an expression for field data because there is already an expression for that field or one of its sub-fields."`,. I'm not sure why Mongodb won't have the same validation for regular query projection. Why is your expected output has other fields from what is projected ? So my question to you what exactly is your requirement ? b/c it won't work if you use aggregation. I'm just trying to understand it better.

Comment: @DhruvPathak if 'data' is included, then all the json subtree of data is included. So there is no point in including 'data' AND 'data.XXX', it's implicit.

Comment: @AgostonHorvath I agree, but inclusion of data.XYZ shall not have precedence over data as a full field, that is a buggy behaviour imo.

Comment: @DhruvPathak it is a bug, given to a buggy query. :) It takes a surprising amount of effort to correctly verify each query. In your case, you want mongodb to do a prefix check on every projection. That takes time away from queries and users who are sane :) and do not need this. E.g. they are using a framework like spring-data-mongo to connect to mongodb.

Comment: @DhruvPathak Yes, it is a bug like mentioned in https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6527. I would still like to know what is bounty for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is unusual behavior, a bug to be precise.

From credible/official sources :

- Jira Open [Bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6527)
- Jira Bug [Duplicate](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6434)

Seems that the bug is still open.

Please let me know if you need any further analysis.

Answer (score 1):

```
db.mycoll.findOne({"_id":1},{"data.amounts.dollar":1,"data":1 })
```

Comment: Thanks.Yes, this permutation works, perhaps mongodb starts evaluating keys from left to right, but I am looking for officially supported documentation or methods

Answer (score 0):

This gives as expected result

```
db.getCollection(coll_name).find({_id:1},{data:1});
```

This will give output

{
    "_id" : 1,
    "data" : {
        "amounts" : {
            "dollar" : 20,
            "euro" : 18
        },
        "item" : "toy",
        "sale" : false
    }
}

Comment: Why you down vote the answer, would you run this query?

Answer (score 0):

Once you use a projection (the second json document in the 'find()', only those fields specified in the projection will be returned by the server (The exception is '_id' which will be returned unless explicitly turned off by _id:0).

{ "data":1 , "data.amounts.dollar":1 }

By selecting data.amounts.dollar inside the sub-document, you have essentially turned off the other members of the data.amounts document.
You can turn them on like you did with dollar, but I think you want them all projected regardless of knowing or not the field names.

I could not find in the documentation anything about order of fields in the projection field.

From the Mongo Documentation here

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#projection-document